# How to parse the json file from the resource folder in ios

Tags: ios, json, resources

i parse the JSON file from local group folder it works fine,but i use the resource group folder it not parsing the JSON file,below is my code,

i use the path for loacl group is

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nbg_ov_t_l_2_2" ofType:@"json"];
```

instead of this line i use for resoure folder ,here 10Template is my resource folder(blue color folder)

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nbg_ov_t_l_2_2" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"10Template"];//From resourse folder..

NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSError *error12 =  nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error12];

NSArray *jsonIdList=jsonDataArray[@"images"];
 for(NSDictionary *tempIdList in jsonIdList)
 {
     NSString *orientation1;
     orientation1=tempIdList[@"orientation"];
     NSLog(@"orientation %@",orientation1);
 }
```

here is my JSON File

```
{
"background_image":false,
"template_orientation":"landscape",
"background_colour":{
                "red":202,
                "green":150,
                "blue":100,
                "alpha":50
                },

"images":[
{
        "background_status":false,
        "tilt_angle":0,
        "orientation":"portrait",
        "overlay":false,
        "rect":
        {
        "x":0,
        "y":0,
        "width":100,
        "height":100
        }
},
{
        "background_status":false,
        "tilt_angle":25,
        "orientation":"landscape",
        "overlay":true,
        "rect":
        {
        "x":25,
        "y":60,
        "width":30,
        "height":50
        }
    }
]
}
```

And also i have another doubt, how to get some json files from local(i.e i have 10 json files means i want to get three only and i parse that three only) and how to parse it.
help me...

Comment: So what is the path that you try to load the JSON from? Is it the same JSON? What errors are returned?

Comment: if i use the file form group folder it works, but i use the same file in the resource group it not gives the path path null is my error

Comment: And you checked that the folder is added to the target, so it will be copied to the app during the build?